# Pandas Pivot with datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I am having some troubles pivoting a dataframe with a datetime value as the index. 
my df looks like this:

```
Timestamp           Value
2016-01-01 00:00:00 16.546900
2016-01-01 01:00:00 16.402375
2016-01-01 02:00:00 16.324250
```

Where the timestamp is a, datetime64[ns]. I am trying to pivot the table so that it looks like this.

```
Hour       0    1    2    4   ....
Date
2016-01-01 16.5 16.4 16.3 17  ....
....
....
```

I've tried using the code below but am getting an error when I run it.

```
df3 =  pd.pivot_table(df2,index=np.unique(df2.index.date),columns=np.unique(df2.index.hour),values=df2.Temp)
```

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      1 # Pivot Table
----> 2 df3 = pd.pivot_table(df2,index=np.unique(df2.index.date),columns=np.unique(df2.index.hour),values=df2.Temp)
```

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py in pivot_table(data, values, index, columns, aggfunc, fill_value, margins, dropna, margins_name)
     56         for i in values:
     57             if i not in data:
---> 58                 raise KeyError(i)
     59 
     60         to_filter = []

KeyError: 16.5469

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I slightly extended input data like below (assuming no duplicated entries in the same date/hour)

```
Timestamp           Value
2016-01-01 00:00:00 16.546900
2016-01-01 01:00:00 16.402375
2016-01-01 02:00:00 16.324250
2016-01-01 04:00:00 16.023928
2016-01-03 04:00:00 16.101919
2016-01-05 23:00:00 13.405928
```

It looks a bit awkward, but something like below works.

```
df2['Date'] = df2.Timestamp.apply(lambda x: str(x).split(" ")[0])
df2['Hour'] = df2.Timestamp.apply(lambda x: str(x).split(" ")[1].split(":")[0])
df3 = pd.pivot_table(df2, values='Value', index='Date', columns='Hour')
```

[Output]

```
Hour        00      01        02        04          23
Date                    
2016-01-01  16.5469 16.402375 16.32425  16.023928   NaN
2016-01-03  NaN     NaN       NaN       16.101919   NaN
2016-01-05  NaN     NaN       NaN       NaN         13.405928
```

Finally if your columns need to be integer,

```
df3.columns = [int(x) for x in df3.columns]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! This did the trick. I think it was the lambda function that did most of the heavy lifting. Didnt need it on the Hour but needed for the date.

Answer (score 4):

A different way of accomplishing this without the `lambda` is to create the indices from the `DateTimeIndex`.

```
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, index=df.index.date, columns=df.index.hour, values="Value")
```

Comment: your comment is not relevant either any more. ;) Please do not encourage people to remove or delete comments, comment history  is good thing to have, people might be trying that "irrelevant" thing now days and now we don't know what it was :(

Answer (score 0):

Adapting @Seanny123 's answer above for an arbitrary cadence:

```
start = [2018, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
end = [date.today().year, date.today().month, date.today().day]
quant='freq'
sTime_tmp = datetime.datetime(start[0], start[1], start[2], tzinfo = pytz.UTC)
eTime_tmp = datetime.datetime(end[0], end[1], end[2], tzinfo = pytz.UTC)
cadence = '5min'
t = pd.date_range(start=sTime_tmp,
                  end=eTime_tmp,
                  freq = cadence)
keo = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=t, columns=[quant])
keo[quant] = 0
keo = pd.pivot_table(keo, index=keo.index.time, columns=keo.index.date, values=quant)

keo
```